# MongoDB query embedded document array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f3817"),
    "_userId" : ObjectId("590a08dba07c1a1bee87b310"),
    "name" : "My home",
    "floors" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4541"),
            "name" : "Floor 1",
            "rooms" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4551"),
                    "name" : "Room 1",
                    "devices" : [
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4561"),
                            "name" : "Device 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4562"),
                            "name" : "Device 2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4552"),
                    "name" : "Room 2",
                    "devices" : [
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4563"),
                            "name" : "Device 3"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4564"),
                            "name" : "Device 4"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4542"),
            "name" : "Floor 2",
            "rooms" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4553"),
                    "name" : "Room 1",
                    "devices" : [
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4565"),
                            "name" : "Device 5"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4566"),
                            "name" : "Device 6"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4554"),
                    "name" : "Room 2",
                    "devices" : [
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4567"),
                            "name" : "Device 7"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4568"),
                            "name" : "Device 8"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I would like to get a list of all devices:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4561"),
        "name" : "Device 1"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4562"),
        "name" : "Device 2"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4563"),
        "name" : "Device 3"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4564"),
        "name" : "Device 4"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4565"),
        "name" : "Device 5"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4566"),
        "name" : "Device 6"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4567"),
        "name" : "Device 7"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59299670266cc82a042f4568"),
        "name" : "Device 8"
    }
]
```

Is that possible with MongoDB?

I've tried it with aggregate and `{ $unwind: $floors.rooms.devices }` or

```
{ $unwind: $floors }
{ $unwind: $floors.rooms }
{ $unwind: $floors.rooms.devices }
```

but the output is always empty. I don't know if I would get the output I want with $unwind at all.

Because I'm also using aggregate for other things a solution with it would be nice.

Comment: Unless you are actually "aggregating" something or otherwise "reducing" the results returned from the server ( for which this really does not qualify ) then you should not be using aggregation. It is often quicker and cleaner for such transforms to simply manipulate the returned documents from the cursor. So your statement of *"..using aggregate for other things.."* is basically the same as saying *"I use a chainsaw to cut down a tree, so I may as well cut my toast with it!"*. `$unwind ` is quite costly, as are other operations just to transform this document.

Comment: This is basically a one liner in the shell: `db.device.find({}, { "_id": 0, "floors.rooms.devices": 1 }).forEach( doc => [].concat.apply([],[].concat.apply([],doc.floors.map( d => d.rooms )).map( d => d.devices )).forEach(d => printjson(d)))` A simple cursor iteration with no additional overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$reduce` to collect all the devices inside all rooms across all floors in a single document in 3.4 version.

The below query has two parts inner reduce and outer reduce.

The inner reduce will collect all the devices, `$reduc`ing one room at a time and concatenating with the previous room's devices arrays in a single floor element.

The output from the inner reduce is piped to the outer `$reduce` to concat devices across all floors.

Something like

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [{
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "devices": {
                "$reduce": {
                    "input": "$floors",
                    "initialValue": [],
                    "in": {
                        "$concatArrays": [
                            "$$value",
                            {
                                "$reduce": {
                                    "input": "$$this.rooms",
                                    "initialValue": [],
                                    "in": {
                                        "$concatArrays": [
                                            "$$value",
                                            "$$this.devices"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }]
)
```

For MongoDB Version < 3.4

You can use the below pipeline. Use `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` option on `$unwind` to prevent pipeline from dropping documents when any of the below arrays is missing, null or empty.

```
db.collection.aggregate(    
    [
      { "$unwind": "$floors" },
      { "$unwind": "$floors.rooms" },
      { "$unwind": "$floors.rooms.devices" },
      { "$group":{ "_id":"$_id", "devices":{ "$push":"$floors.rooms.devices"} } }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I prefer the second solution because it looks much cleaner and simpler. But how could I get only the devices of a certain room with this solution?

Comment: Np. You can add `$match` stage after `$unwind`ing rooms. Something like`{$match:{"floors.rooms":room query}}`

Comment: I've tried `{ $match: { 'floors.rooms': { _id: ObjectId('59299670266cc82a042f4551') } } }` after `{ $unwind: '$floors.rooms' }` but without result. What's wrong?

Comment: Try  `{ $match: { 'floors.rooms_id': ObjectId('59299670266cc82a042f4551') } }`. More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match: {}},
{$unwind: "$floors"},    
{$unwind: "$floors.rooms"},
{$unwind: "$floors.rooms.devices"},
{$group: {
    _id: "$floors.rooms._id",
    d1: {$push: "$floors.rooms.devices"}
}},   
{$unwind:"$d1"},
{$group: {
    _id: "ignore-me",
    devices: {$push: "$d1"}
}} 

]).pretty();
```